# Integration test webapi core Authorization fiter

Tags: testing, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I would like to write and integration test for ASP.NET Core 6 Web API  for `Authorisation` filter.

I would like to write integration test to validate authorization filter. any advice

I am getting an error

> testhost.deps.json'. This file is required for functional tests to run properly. There should be a copy of the file on your source project bin folder. If that is not the case, make sure that the property PreserveCompilationContext is set to true on your project file. E.g 'true'. For functional tests to work they need to either run from the build output folder or the testhost.deps.json file from your application's output directory must be copied to the folder where the tests are running on. A common cause for this error is having shadow copying enabled when the tests run.

Code:

```
public class IntegrationTest
{
    protected readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    protected IntegrationTest()
    {
        var appFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
        _httpClient = appFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    protected async Task AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("barer", await GetJetAsync());
    }

    private async Task<string> GetJetAsync()
    {
        string token = "eOCwiZXhwIjoxNjUyMzE1NzI4LCJhenAiOiJmN3B2OHFtUmoyaXFHS0xQbW1KYkIzdmNTQWN1UjlsZiIsInNjb3BlIjoib3BlbmlkIHByb2ZpbGUgZW1haWwgYWRkcmVzcyBwaG9uZSByZWFkOnByb2ZpbGUgcmVhZDpwcmVmZXJlbmNlcyB1cGRhdGU6cHJvZmlsZSB1cGRhdGU6cHJlZmVyZW5jZXMgdXBkYXRlOnByb2R1Y3QtbGlzdCByZWFkOnByb2R1Y3QtbGlzdCB1cGRhdGU6bG95YWx0eS1hY2NvdW50IHJlYWQ6bG95YWx0eS1hY2NvdW50IHJlYWQ6Y29sIHVwZGF0ZTpjb2wgc3NvOmNvbCBvZmZsaW5lX2FjY2VzcyIsImd0eSI6InBhc3N3b3JkIn0.blVb5UFO4sU0k3hptbbwXBk6RWGSr60wrsFlQTNbY76XyuqQgMNfU2SHHRq7qnaaC3UdMeYk4HJctfQDH8J3_itth2tF0FopHf_dUnxSnwq9Ga1dw4FXlscTwBUVEvzg_Q3VnhNL7Q8XWyfSthX4laatJ6_6X6cbGM6mdMNl5-8iSp3KH3GUbD3oOLZDKYylFJCxM2227FpPcdH-vI9I54Bqdtvs-2LPvClu-nsUEjo8no87G_llsjBEsEHmQO31Svq8h_8peumS_gpqOOwM6lAhulQcZOnd3m7-LfgGoXKLbJdXuw1rgEWbb-bD8bm7_dJ3i0Q99dkagY4RW6SHaQ";
        return await Task.Run(() => token);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetAll_ReturnsOK()
    {
        await AuthenticateAsync();
        string uri = "https://localhost:9999/products";
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you debug your code and check which line makes such error?

Comment: Unrelated but your “Authenticate” and “GetJet” functions don’t need to be async. Also, when you call “GetAsync” you don’t need to specify the base url, the client does that for you.